# java.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, batch-file, ant, cmd, windows-server-2008

I have already read some posts but I cant solve my problem yet.

I am working on a remote desktop and windows server 2008. In the shared disk E: I put some batch file. This batch files call a new batch file from server which runs `java` script. And now I am taking the this message.

`java.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

I try to set the environment like :

First setup the JRE7 to disk E

Second create new user variable which name is `JAVA_HOME` and which path is my JRE path `E:\Tool\BatFiles`

But I am still taking this error. Where should I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting JAVA_HOME is a good step, and with it you should be able to run Java as follows

```
%JAVA_HOME%/java myProgram arg0
```

If you don't want to include `%JAVA_HOME` in your command, you will have to include it in your `PATH`. Windows checks it's `PATH` for bin scripts every time a command is called. A typical Java installation does this for you.

You can edit your `PATH` to include `;%JAVA_HOME%` at the end. Restart your command prompt for changes to take effect.

**Edit 1**
Be careful when editting your PATH however! Windows depends on it to function in many aspects. You can expect `explorer` to stop working. Make sure before altering your `PATH` variable, that you back it up somewhere. Just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Roberto , but the problem is, I have no any `PATH`variable. I only have `TEMP`and `TMP` variables. So first should i create `PATH` variable  ?

Comment: You're probably editing User Variables. `PATH` is a system variable that you may or may not have access to. If you create a new `PATH` user variable like you suggested, it should append to the system path as normal. Give it a shot :)

Comment: Like you said, Accessing the System Variable is forbidden. So i will try to create a user variable. I hope it works :)

Comment: Let me know if it does :)

Comment: It doesn't work :/ or I cannot succeed it, I don't know. The problem is anyone can use this batch file because i put it in public folder so  everyone should work with this batch correctly but i cannot do it :/

Comment: @BatuhanBardak if you can't change system variable, and would like to make your batch file accessible to all users, maybe you need to add full path name of `%JAVA_HOME%` in your batch file.