# How to install jmeter on a windows 7 laptop correctly?

Tags: jmeter

I am having trouble installing jmeter on my Windows 7 laptop. It is possible that the files are not being properly unzipped. Having followed a tutorial on YouYube, I am encountering the following error when trying to run the jmeter.bat file:

***'java.exe' is not recognised as aninternal or external commmand, operable program or batch file...'***

Perhaps if someone could explain this error, I will get to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Getting Started: Scripting with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/get-started-scripting-jmeter) guide:

> Note that you need to have JRE 1.6 or above to run Jmeter, because
>   it's written in pure JAVA.

So if you don't have it, obtain JRE (or better JDK) of current version from [Oracle Java SE Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), install it to your hard drive (I would recommend putting it under location without spaces in path, i.e. `c:\Java` rather than `c:\Program Files\`

Find `jmeter.bat` file and add next lines to the very beginning:

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\Java
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH
```

That should be more than enough to launch JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to incorrectly setting java home path..

Set %JAVA_HOME% correctly in system environment variables

eg: `JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06`

For more details [java.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218354/java-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)